# can we call the internal javascript function from another internal javascript function from another html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am new to javascript . I have a doubt that can we call the internal javascript function from another internal javascript function from another html??

For example:

consider two html a.html and b.html i want to call b.html javascript function from  a.html and i want to pass a parameter.

a.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc(variable){
xyz(variable);//where xyz function in b.html
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

b.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function xyz(variable){
    alert('message::'+variable);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Is this possible or is there any other way to do this???

Comment: It can be possible if b.html is parent of a.html, What i mean is you have open kind of new window named a.html from b.html

Comment: You need to use a comman js file and write function over there and use script tag for this,

Comment: Use templating precisely (There is Facelets for this on JSF side).

Comment: If i bring it in the common js file, can i trigger that alert whenever i call abc() function. My problem is that i want to display an alert in one screen(when i want to display is when i am calling abc() function).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

- You can use html imports
- XHR, select the script with getElemntsByTagName, and eval its content
- parenting

I do not recommend any.

Comment: Sorry am not clear , should you explain me more clear??